# Технология проверки компиляторов

Tags: компилятор, тестирование, компиляция

Как проверяют компиляторы вообще? На соответствие стандартам (при разборе кода), на корректность генерируемого кода (вообще и с оптимизацией)? Например, для компилятора языка Си, как широко распространённого.

Стандарты гигантские же, да и возможных конструкций и сочетаний может быть дофига. Просто набор тестов или что-то иное?

Comment: Ну, стандарты являются спецификацией, а дальше обычные себе юнит-тесты, как для любой программы. Плюс ещё отдельно тесты оптимизатора, которые не определяются спецификацией языка, но определяются тех. заданием на оптимизатор.

Comment: Дедушка Кнут вот как-то написал тестовые файлы для компилятора TeX'а: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tripman.pdf

Comment: @alexlz: Ну, сравнительно недавно вот MiKTeX под форточки появился, до него под линуксом был написан teTeX, и ещё emTeX под DOS.

Comment: а кто проверяет тех, кто проверяет компиляторы?

Comment: @VladD MikTeX, ежели мне склероз не изменяет, появился в прошлом тысячелетии. teTeX вроде закрылся, автор переключался на поддержку LiveTeX'а. Но всё это **дистрибутивы**, к исходному коду TeX'а отношения не имеющие. Код написан Кнутом на языке WEB, а эти дистрибутивы, если не ошибаюсь, используют порт web2c, с дальнейшей трансляцией сишного кода.

А в дистрибутивы, кроме собственно TeX и Metafont входит много каких расширений (наиболее известное -- LaTeX), но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Когда-то один мой друг правил gcc для кросс компиляции на 16-бит PDP-11 (рабочие среды 32-bit MC68020 и VAX).

Так для проверки кросс собрали bsd 2.9, загрузились (на Электронике-79 (она же PDP)) , пересобрали ее же на себе самой, загрузились уже в ней и поигрались (насколько у кого фантазии хватило).

Вряд ли это можно считать исчерпывающим тестированием, но хоть какая-то уверенность появилась.

Comment: @alexlz: MiKTeX не web2c, насколько я понимаю. И emTeX был тоже.

Comment: @renegator: проверяют пользователи, конечно. На одном только SO [>13K вопросов](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compiler+bug).

Comment: @VladD поскольку самому искать лень, не подкинете ли ссылки на TeX из MikTeX'а и emTeX'а?

Что касается компиляторов, то для ады: http://www.adaic.org/community/compilers-conformity/ . Но ada, как детище Пентагона, язык особый.

Comment: @alexlz: MikTeX вот: [miktex.org](http://miktex.org/). emTeX уже давненько не используется, нашёл на CTAN'e: [CTAN:systems/msdos/emtex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/msdos/emtex). (У меня дома в пыльном углу винта до сих пор лежит русифицированный дистрибутив.)

Comment: @alexlz: а мне-то как лениво! :-) Гугл вот подсказал: [сообщение в ньюсгруппе](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.text.tex/PYiKhvlM0G8), [исходники MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/sources). Кроме того, web2c-версии выдают при старте что-то наподобие

> This is TeX, Version 3.14159 (Web2C 7.4.5)

Comment: @VladD Ну скачал я эти 21M архива. Разбираться там -- нафиг. Как оно строится -- без понятия, виндов нет, MS VS -- тем более. В tex.web версия 3.1415926. Как оно преобразуется в C мне неважно (а паскаля в MS VS вроде нет). И. боюсь, мы говорим о разных вещах. Я не знаю, что в мире теха означает 'web2c дистрибутив', да и не важно. Или я чего-то не заметил, или упомянутый выше tex.web и есть текст теха (версия 2008 г.).

Comment: @alexlz: "web2c-дистрибутив" -- это означает, что он получен непосредственно из Кнутовского TEX.WEB при помощи транслятора web2c (который транслирует язык WEB в C).

Comment: @VladD Теперь осталось только, чтобы кто-нибудь сказал, как же транслируется тех в этом miktex'е.

Answer (score 1):

"The LLVM Compiler Infrastructure" имеет "LLVM Test Suite" набор юнит тестов компиляция которых может считаться необходимым условием правильной установки backtend. CLANG/GCC - имеют свои наборы тестов. К тому же, эти проекты имеют свои багтрекеры, на которых отмечаю замеченные проблемы. Например когда Линус нашел проблему в бете GCC 5.0, об этом узнали все  it-сми.

Answer (score 0):

1. Так же, как и прочие программы: тестами.
2. Автоматическмими доказывалками теорем (если я правильно понял): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompCert

Также компилятор Си, написанный на Си, должен уметь скомпилировать свой исходный код. Причём если такая цепочка сходится (то есть получился такой же исполняемый файл), то это хороший знак.